# Interior Content Background wont display in IE

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I am struggling to get my interior background image to display in IE, works fine in FF and chrome. Cant figure it out.

```
    <div id="banner">
        <div id="banner-image"><cms:CMSEditableImage ID="BannerPhoto" runat="server" ImageHeight="284" ImageWidth="892" /></div>
    </div>

    <div id="interior-content-block">
        <div id="repeating-content">
            <div id="interior-content">
                <cc1:CMSEditableRegion ID="txtMain" runat="server" DialogHeight="312" RegionType="HtmlEditor" RegionTitle="Main Content" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="side-navigation">
            <cms:CMSListMenu ID="CMSListMenuSub" runat="server" HighlightAllItemsInPath="true" ClassNames="CMS.MenuItem" RenderCssClasses="true" CSSPrefix="side1;side2" DisplayHighlightedItemAsLink="true" Path="/{0}/%"/>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

```
#repeating-content-landing
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
    background: #959398 url(../site-images/landing-page/final-landing-page-design.jpg);
    width: 820px;
}

#interior-content
{
    padding: 32px 32px 32px 32px;
    background: #999999 url(../site-images/interior-content.gif)repeat-y;
    min-height: 312px;
}

#interior-content-landing
{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: #999999 url(../site-images/landing-page/final-landing-page-design.jpg) no-repeat;
    min-height: 700px;
}

<style />
```

Comment: Why isn't your style tagged with <style></style> and It's not on header. If CSS is suppose to be separate, please say that.

Comment: Sorry for that.  It has been edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the CSS does not parse correctly unless the property values are spaced out properly. You have no space between your url and repeat:

From:

```
background: #999999 url(../site-images/interior-content.gif)repeat-y;
```

To:

```
background: #999999 url(../site-images/interior-content.gif) repeat-y;
```

Comment: Thanks Jage, that was it! I was editing the css in a cms and it looked as if there was a space there.  Silly mistake that cost me 3 hours. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The other thing to try is to break the individual items apart:

```
background-image: url(images/yourImage.png); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: center
```

Hope this helps.